# How to authorize Dropbox using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have configured omniauth, omniauth-dropbox and devise for authentication using Dropbox. But every time I sign in using Dropbox it asks to authorize the app for the Dropbox account, even though I have authorized it once. How do you stop re-authorization on every time a user signs in?

I am using https://github.com/spagalloco/omniauth-dropbox as Dropbox strategy.

Comment: I havent read the docs but i would imagine it would be something similar to the google contacts api where you can pass an approval prompt option after the key and secret, so something like this { :approval_prompt => "false"}

Comment: Not working, any other suggestions

Comment: that was an example of what the google contact api does, you need to search the docs to find the equivalent for dropbox, of course it was never going to work, it was for a different api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [pass the authorised session to the DropboxClient](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/authentication#ruby):

```
# This will fail if the user didn't visit the above URL and hit 'Allow'
session.get_access_token

client = DropboxClient.new(session, ACCESS_TYPE)
```